# Flag inappropriate documentation requests & tags

Tags: feature-request, documentation

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wordpress/topic-requests/2555

On this the op requests a topic explaining

```
"what wordpress plugins are out there and which is best for my website"
```

I don't want to be overzealous, but obviously if someone was to create documentation (loose meaning) for this, it would be either far too broad and extremely opinionated.

**Is there a mechanism planned to flag topic requests as low quality, maybe to recommend the op defines the request to a narrower topic?**

Also just looking at the topics entered so far in wordpress/php/etc, there are no tags to categorize content. Obviously google will be one route to find content but it would be nice to have categories to search by.

**Are there plans to introduce categories?**

Comment: You can comment on the request...

Comment: The `which is best for my website` part makes this request too narrow, not too broad. Documentation topics are *supposed* to be far too broad for the Q&A format.

Comment: @dorukayhan bizarre remark for a feature request. The op did not specify what kind of website or what they wanted to achieve, hence the term "broad" ... or if you prefer, "narrow". With either meaning, what function/class/process is there to document?

Comment: It wouldn't have mattered if they specified that sort of thing.  What that documentation request was doing was asking for one very specific and very narrow-in-scope thing, not focused on the programming community-at-large, but rather their own needs for their website.  Nothing could *ever* save that request.